# How to get the sample frequency axis in R?

Tags: r, plot, fft, frequency-analysis

Im trying to plot a time series data in the frequency domain in R. I have a csv file with columns/signals `x`, `y` and `z`. The Signal has been sampled with frequency of 50 Hz. Length of the data are `N=651`.

I did the following steps for the column/signal `x`:

1. FFT of signal `x`:

   `y <- fft(data$x)`
2. Calcluating the magnitude of signal `x`:

   `mag <- sqrt(Re(y)^2+Im(y)^2)`
3. Plot the data:

   `plot(mag, xlab="Samples",ylab="Strength", type="l", col="blue", xlim=c(0,60), main="Spectrum",t="h",lwd=2)`

What I want is to get an x-axis in frequenzy(Hz) instead of number of samples. In the end I want to get a plot with y-axis (strength) vs. x-axis (Hz).

I want a frequency axis like this: 10Hz,20Hz,30Hz,40Hz,50Hz, etc.

What do I need to do to get the frequency axis in Hz instead of number of samples?

Comment: Please plot your final fft spectrum so we can try  and determine if your spectrum is correct, i have a feeling you might not understand FFT binning.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
plot(mag, 
     xlab="Samples",
     ylab="Strength",
     type="l",
     col="blue",
     xlim=c(0,
            60),
     main="Spectrum",
     t="h",
     lwd=2,
     axes=F)# don't plot the default axes
#build our own axes with labels
box()
axis(2)
ticks <- axTicks(1)
axis(1,at=ticks,labels=paste0(format(ticks),'Hz'))
```